# Rails 3- Nested object being created through form, but no attributes saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I've found similar questions, but none have helped in this specific instance. I have a Verifications model and an Uploads model. When users create a Verification they also may add Uploads to it. My verifications are created just fine, and an Upload is created (just one, however, and I'll need to be able to add many uploads). However, every attribute for the upload is saved as nil. I can create uploaded files just fine through its own form, but just not in the nested form.

Form view

```
<%= nested_form_for @verification do |f| %>

  ...

      <%= f.fields_for :uploads do |upload_form| %>
        <%= upload_form.label :select_file %>
        <%= upload_form.file_field :data %>
        <%= upload_form.link_to_remove "Remove this file" %>
      <% end %>
      <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a file", :uploads %></p>
<% end %>

<%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

verification.rb

```
class Verification < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :uploads_attributes

  has_many :uploads, autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :uploads, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

end
```

verifications_controller.rb

```
class VerificationsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @verification = Verification.new(params[:verification])
        @uploads = Upload.new(params[:uploads_attributes])
     end

    def create
        @verification = Verification.new(params[:verification])
        @verification.save
        @verification.uploads.create
    end
```

Output:

```
Started POST "/verifications" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-13 11:00:04 -0500
Processing by VerificationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3an81f1MRLGXexkBA9hcBuRdAdIb1XNWLhPRC60FSa0=", "verification"=>{"project_id"=>"1", "checked_on"=>"", "notes"=>"", "uploads_attributes"=>{"1394725257840"=>{"data"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x445f320 @original_filename="test.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"verification[uploads_attributes][1394725257840][data]\"; filename=\"test.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:C:/Users/kctsrk/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20140313-2704-bs31i7>>, "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "compliance"=>"Compliant"}, "commit"=>"Create Verification"}
  [1m[35mAccount Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."remember_token" = '2-4ARijYLtx4uSpV2A7oWA' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mProject Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36mProject Exists (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT 1 AS one FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (1.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "verifications" ("account_id", "approved", "attachment", "attachment2", "checked_on", "compliance", "created_at", "dateimplemented", "notes", "project_id", "project_name", "state_id", "submitted_on", "updated_at", "verifier_name") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["account_id", 1], ["approved", true], ["attachment", nil], ["attachment2", nil], ["checked_on", nil], ["compliance", "Compliant"], ["created_at", Thu, 13 Mar 2014 16:00:04 UTC +00:00], ["dateimplemented", 2014-03-13 11:00:04 -0500], ["notes", ""], ["project_id", 1], ["project_name", nil], ["state_id", 4], ["submitted_on", nil], ["updated_at", Thu, 13 Mar 2014 16:00:04 UTC +00:00], ["verifier_name", nil]]
  [1m[36m (88.0ms)[0m  [1mcommit transaction[0m
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36mSQL (3.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "uploads" ("created_at", "data", "filename", "mime_type", "name", "updated_at", "verification_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)[0m  [["created_at", Thu, 13 Mar 2014 16:00:04 UTC +00:00], ["data", nil], ["filename", nil], ["mime_type", nil], ["name", nil], ["updated_at", Thu, 13 Mar 2014 16:00:04 UTC +00:00], ["verification_id", 38]]
  [1m[35m (86.0ms)[0m  commit transaction
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mProject Exists (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mcommit transaction[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/verifications/38
Completed 302 Found in 417ms (ActiveRecord: 184.0ms)
```

So it's passing the uploads_attributes, but then not actually using those to create the upload objects.

Comment: you're with rails 3 or 4? seems 3 right?

Comment: Rails 3, I've edited the title to reflect that.

Comment: The attributes are nested **within** the `verification` params. That said, isn't the point of accepting nested params so you don't have to create the nested object manually?

Comment: How do I properly access the attributes within the verification params? I created the nested object manually because otherwise the upload was not created at all.

Comment: @krstck By using normal hash notation as you're already doing. Nested hashes are just hashes; keep accessing by key.